# What's the definition of the EPR limit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, epr-experiment

I am reading this paper, nature.com/articles/s41567-018-0347-x, which is about the generation of high-dimensional entanglement using two non-commuting variables, frequency-bin and time-bin.

On page 7 in this paper, they say that a time-frequency product is higher than the EPR limit of unity so both variables are allowed to be controlled independently. Now I have no idea what it does mean but I think it is related to the Heisenberg uncertainty relation.

Comment: Add some references to your question

Comment: What do you mean by limit or unity?

Comment: Thanks for the reference, @James. Like you, I think this limit is related to the Heisenberg uncertainty relation and specifically when one of the observables that describe your system has an uncertainty below the vacuum state noise... Anyway, it's my first seeing this.